# Why this for loop works by half?

Tags: flutter, loops, hive, flutter-hive

I have a Box from Hive package in flutter. to remove expired objects from local db i define a method with a loop within in initstate() method. bu when i open the class this loop works by half!! what is wrong with that?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  removeExpired();
  }


DateTime nowTime;


void removeExpired() async{
var boxSecure= await Hive.openBox('securityBox');
var box = Hive.box('securityBox');
print('length: ${box.length}');
final nowTime = DateTime.now();
if(box.length>0){
  for(var i = 0 ; i< box.length; ++i) {
    DbSecurity m = box.getAt(i);
    var s= m.registerTime;
    if(nowTime.isAfter(s)){
      box.deleteAt(i);
      print('${i} removed'); // when there are 
    }
    else{
      
    }
  }
}
else{
}
}
```

this is a model :

```
@HiveType(typeId : 0)
class DbSecurity{

@HiveField(0)
String carId;
@HiveField(1)
DateTime registerTime;
@HiveField(2)
String TypeOfCar;
```

and finally when i open the page :

```
 I/flutter ( 9193): length: 6
I/flutter ( 9193): 0 removed
I/flutter ( 9193): 1 removed
I/flutter ( 9193): 2 removed
/////////////////
I/flutter ( 9193): 3
I/flutter ( 9193): length: 3
I/flutter ( 9193): 0 removed
I/flutter ( 9193): 1 removed
```

I try to remove all of the objects that has expired.

Answer (score 2):

You are removing items while iterating the box.
Say at index 2 and index 3 are items to be removed.
Then first `box.deleteAt(2)` will be called.
What happens next is that every other item will shift down an index.
The box that first was at index 3 will be at index 2. But in the next iteration of the loop you are checking index 3, therefore, the original item at 3 will never be checked